# JerseyTest and Spring and creating a ServletContext

Tags: spring, jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm working on migrating from Jersey 1.16 to Jersey 2.7. I have the application running and working, but I'm having trouble with the tests.

Some things to note:
The application uses Spring and is configured by a class, ApplicationConfiguration.class. 
The application does not have a web.xml - the Jersey servlet and filters are configured programmatically.
I am using the jersey-spring3 library.
Related to using the jersey-spring3 library, I have to add a workaround to my onStartup method

```
// The following line is required to avoid having jersey-spring3 registering it's own Spring root     context.
// https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2038
servletContext.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "");
```

Here's the issue:
When the test is starting up, SpringComponentProvider, tries to initialize Spring with a dangerous assumption that I can't figure out how to correct - xml based configuration. Looking at the code, the trouble is this block

```
    ServletContext sc = locator.getService(ServletContext.class);

    if(sc != null) {
        // servlet container
        ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sc);
    } else {
        // non-servlet container
        ctx = createSpringContext();
    }
```

Running a JUnit test, ServletContext is null, and createSpringContext is called.

Here's the question:
Is there a way to run a test and specify a ServletContext/ServletContainer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is covered by https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2259.

In short: they removed this functionality from Jersey 2.x and are treating it as a Feature Request (instead of regression) so it's not considered a high-priority item.